# Function doesn't work after php response

Tags: php, extjs

I have an ajax request sending some data to a php file:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ 
    url: 'update.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (){ alert("saved"); },
    failure: function (){ alert("not saved"); },
    params: { data: someData }
})
```

and update.php that has only two lines:

```
<?php
    $res = array('success' => false);
    echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

The success function is always executed.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the function failure should be called when there is a problem with the request. e.g. If the server is down or the page update.php do not exist anymore.

Comment: If I delete the update.php, the failure function is realy launched, but is there a way to work with php response like here: [link](http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=606)

Comment: Indeed. @lvil, the reason your success function is always being called is because your request is always successful. It doesn't matter that you've put some value in it that says "success" is false. That result is still being successfully returned to you, and if you want to interpret it, that's up to you. If you want it to work like the code on that page you linked to, you have to use the code on that page you linked to -- the success() function there decodes the response data from the server and checks it (`...if (data.success === true)...`)

Answer (score 2):

`Ext.Ajax.success` is executed because the AJAX request was successful. If you rename or delete update.php, it'll execute `.failure` because it's getting a 404.
You have to check the response in `.success` or make update.php return a 404.

Answer (score 2):

`success` is called when the request succeeded. The data you reply with is irrelevant.

The `error` callback is invoked when the request failed. It's not failing, so the callback is not being invoked.

Parse the resultant data within the success callback to look at application-level logic:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ 
    url: 'update.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (data){ alert(data.success ? "saved" : "not saved"); },
    failure: function (){ alert("request failed"); },
    params: { data: someData }
});
```

I have assumed that `success` may take a parameter with the response contents; check the documentation for Ext to find out.

Comment: Which is something I don't like at all in ExtJs. Most of the time I make a "jsonRequest" wrapper which calls the "failure" callback on any error, being within a json response or within an HTTP error.

Comment: @Drasill: The APIs all do this in pretty much the same way, and in my opinion they're right. You're erasing the line between transport errors and logic errors, making your code far less modular and adaptive than it could be.